# postData cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, httpclient

I'm new to Android programing. I'm trying to post some data to a server using post. I googled it up and came up with this:

```
public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");
        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }

   }
```

My problem is I'm getting errors on the first line of this code:

- postData cannot be resolved to a type
- syntax error on token "{", delete this token
- syntax error on token "void",  @ expected

I'm using Eclipse and I used Shift+Ctrl+o to get all the imports.

Comment: your error is probably the line above this...  Are you missing an @Override or closing brace... etc...

Comment: Could you show the whole code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem (based on the information you've given so far) is that you're declaring the function `postData` outside of a class.

Functions in Java need to be declared in a class.  Either, you've accidently close off the previous class by having one too many `}` (in which case you should have an error at the extra `}`), or you haven't declared a class.

The class could look something like this:

```
public class MyPoster {

    public void postData() {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");
        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }

   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried putting the function in a class but it still gave me an error. After some reading I finally figured out what the problem was. I posted only a part of my code. The whole thing was in onCreate method. When I move it outside it started working :)